# Is preprocessor output reduced when compiling?

Tags: c, compilation, c-preprocessor

I'm currently learning the **C** programming language and was curious what output of code I get when using the preprocessor macros. So I ran gcc with the `-E` switch and took a look at the output and was a bit surprised. The total output was bigger than expected. After reading through this: http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/cpp.html I realized that this behaviour is intended, but a question (which I couldn't find answered when using google) remains: Is most of the code that is included optimized away when entering the next compiling phase? For example, the generated code contained `typedefs` of `__u_char` or definitions of `memcpy` and such alike which are not used in my program. When I get the generated executable format, are these references still somehow existent, or removed from the compiler/assembler?

Comment: 0) `int main(void) { return 0; }` 1) run gcc -E on it. 2) run gcc -S on it. 3) yes: most of it is *optimised away* , the resulting assembler code only contains the `return 0;` part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are just "prototypes" for the functions, allowing you to refer to them in your code. They don't take up any space themselves at all. Only the code for the functions you use will actually be copied to the executable from the library itself.